# Contar valores iguales tras contar valores distintos

Tags: sql

Tengo un campo con países.
Con esta query

```
SELECT COUNT(CustomerID), Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY COUNT(CustomerID) DESC
```

llego a esto:

| COUNT(CustomerID) | Country |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | USA |
| 4 | Canadá |
| 4 | España |
| 3 | Japón |

Yo quiero contar la cantidad de veces que se repiten los count.

Mi objetivo:

| Number | COUNT() |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 1 |

Probé varias cosas. Select dentro de Select, group by pero no estoy lograndolo.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda o guía desde ya y quedo atento por si no está claro el planteo.

Gracias!

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: pone el select que intentaste, ya que lo que estas pidiendo se resuelve haciendo exactamente lo mismo que estas haciendo ahora....

Comment: Bruno, si la respuesta te fue util pro favor marcala como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Total, Count(Total)
From (SELECT COUNT(CustomerID) as Total, Country
FROM Customers
GROUP BY Country
ORDER BY COUNT(CustomerID) DESC)
Group by Total;
```

En esta consulta ponemos en la **clausula from** tu consulta original, tal como si de una tabla se tratase, porque en esencia una consulta no es mas que un conjunto de registros.

La consulta interna devuelve un conjunto de registros con dos columnas: Total y Country. Sobre esta consulta hacemos una que usara solamente la columna total y contamos la cantidad de veces que sale ese numero como normalmente se haria, usando la **funcion Count** y la **clausula Group By**.

En resumen, primero se hace la consulta interna y sobre el resultado que devuelve esta consulta interna se hace otra consulta devolviendo los datos que queremos